# How to create an empty python virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

When creating a new environment with conda we get a completely empty virtual environment:

```
conda create --name=test
conda activate test
conda list
```

The output of the last command is an empty list, there's not even `pip` installed. I'd like to achieve the same result with python `venv` command (or at least have the "minimal" virtual environment with only `pip` installed). When I run `python -m venv test` the new environment contains all packages available "system-wide":

```
python -m venv test
source test/bin/activate
pip freeze
```

outputs a long list of packages.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/venv.html) the command has `--system-site-packages` parameter but it looks like it's on by default, I can't find a way to disable it. I've also tried using the old virtualenv `--clear` parameter but obviously it's not taken into account.

EDIT:

It turned out to be the environment modules `module` command interfering with python modules (https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). After running `module purge` `pip freeze` returns empty list.

Comment: Hm. Not terribly familiar with `venv` yet, but I repeated the steps above and got no output from `pip freeze`. What version of Python 3 are you using?

Comment: How exactly do you call module purge command? I tried and it says: command not found. What would be the exact command?

Comment: Hmmm I think it's installation specific. Here's the documentation: https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#subcmd-purge I've been using my university's machines where `module` was installed (I guess for security purposes), perhaps you don't need `module` command at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT:

try the following:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.4

$ python3 -m venv test_venv

$ source ./test_venv/bin/activate

$ pip list

Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.0.3 
setuptools 40.8.0 
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(test_venv) 

$ pip freeze
(test_venv)
```

If you have `virtualenv` installed, to create a 'fresh' virtual env without "system wide" pip packages, try the following:

```
# create new folder:
$ mkdir test_venv

# create virtual env:
$ virtualenv test_venv/

# activate virtual env:
$ source ./test_venv/bin/activate

# list packages in virtual env (test_venv):
$ pip list

Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.2.3 
setuptools 41.2.0 
wheel      0.33.6 
(test_venv)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately `virtualenv` is not an option, python 2 retires at the end of this year (https://pythonclock.org/) and the documentation of `virtualenv` itself mentions `venv` for python 3 (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/#compare-contrast-with-alternatives).

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer. I'm able to get a fresh virtual env with `python3 -m venv test_venv`. I have included my python3 version. Maybe you could check the version of Python3 that you're using.

Comment: I have tried calling python3 -m venv ./my_venv/ but the virtual environment involves system wide packages. My intent was to create a clean virtual environment. After activating, pip list gives quite a lot of packages. I did not place --system-site-packages argument in venv command. Does anyone have similar experience? Also pyenv.cfg has include-system-site-packages set to false. On the other hand, pip list gives a long list of packages installed system-wide that I do not wish to appear in virtual environment.

Comment: Anyone found a solution? I'm having the exact same behaviour as @MiroslavRadojević and this is incredibly annoying.

Answer (score 3):

A configuration file `pyvenv.cfg` should be located within the virtual environment's root directory when we create a virtual environment with `venv`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) this file should contain a line with an `include-system-site-packages` key and set to `false` if `venv` previously was run without the `--system-site-packages` option.

Comment: `$ cat pyvenv.cfg`   
```home = /usr/local/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.7.4``` Yes, it's set to false. Is this not the default?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create a virtual environment with a specific python version. This is what I did.
Installled `virtualenv`

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Go to the python version download page (with binary installers). In my case I needed python 3.7, so the latest release with binay installers was version 3.7.9 https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379/

Go to that page and downloaded `Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file`
extracted the zip file and placed the contents inside the project folder.

Then used,

```
virtualenv --python .\python379\python.exe env
```

To create the virtual environment.

If you get any error like `virtualenv: The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,` uninstall `virtualenv` using `pip uninstall virtualenv`, close the terminal, open terminal as Administrator / root user and install again.