# Python3.4 venv - Global packages included

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-3.4, virtual-environment

I'm using a project where python3.4 is required for some other dependencies.. Downloaded version 3.4.10 from python.org, installed it and it works fine. Then I'm creating a Pyhthon3.4.10 venv and activating it:

```
$ python3.4 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

To check that the venv is activated:

```
$ which python
../venv/bin/python

$ python -V
Python 3.4.10
```

All good. Check pip list:

```
$ pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ----------------------
absl-py                       0.9.0
alabaster                     0.7.12
anaconda-client               1.7.2
anaconda-navigator            1.9.12
.....
```

The strange thing now is that all my global packages is included. When creating venv's with higher versions of python this never happens. I'm expecting this:

```
$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.2.3 
setuptools 41.2.0
```

venv should be compatible with this version, no? Can't figure out what's the problem here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an empty python virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000371/how-to-create-an-empty-python-virtual-environment)

Comment: Check `which pip`. Check if you have `$PYTHONPATH` (shouldn't be defined). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1382925/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+global+package